# modify a dynamically created button inside its click event

Tags: android

This is my Android code to create a table, table rows and text view and button in each table row dynamically. The buttons initially say "Select". When clicked, the button text should change to "Remove" and when clicked again, they should display "Select". I created a click event for each button and it is firing properly. However, inside the click event, I am not able to change the button text.

```
//Create dynamic table
for (int i =0; i<pList.size(); i++) {
   dynamicTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableID);
   dynamicRow = new TableRow(this);

   //add label to row
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText(pList.get(i));
   tv.setWidth(200);
   dynamicRow.addView(tv);

   //add select button to row
   dynamicBtn = new Button(this);
   dynamicBtn.setText("Select");
   dynamicBtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(pList.get(i)));
   dynamicBtn.setWidth(200);
   dynamicRow.addView(dynamicBtn);

   dynamicBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               if (dynamicBtn.getText().toString().contentEquals("Select"))
                               {
                                   selectedList.add( Integer.toString(dynamicBtn.getId()) );
                                   //This part is not working
                                   dynamicBtn.setText("Remove");

                               }
                               else if (dynamicBtn.getText().toString().contentEquals("Remove"))
                               {
                                   selectedList.remove( Integer.toString(dynamicBtn.getId()) );
                                   dynamicBtn.setText("Select");
                               }
                           }
                       });

   dynamicTable.addView(dynamicRow);
```

}

Comment: "I am not able to change the button text." What does that mean exactly? You are getting a compile error? It compiles but doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Fweigl Not compilation errors. I was not getting the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
It reuses the view v and not the variable outside the scope.

```
dynamicBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {

                               Button btn = (Button) v;

                               if (btn.getText().toString().contentEquals("Select"))
                               {
                                   selectedList.add( Integer.toString(btn.getId()) );                               
                                 btn.setText("Remove");

                               }
                               else if (btn.getText().toString().contentEquals("Remove"))
                               {
                                   selectedList.remove( Integer.toString(btn.getId()) );
                                   btn.setText("Select");
                               }
                           }
                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick.

```
dynamicBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               if(dynamicBtn.getText().equals("Select")){
                                    dynamicBtn.setText("Remove");
                               }
                               elseif(dynamicBtn.getText().equals("Remove")){
                                    dynamicBtn.setText("Select");
                               }                                 
                           }
                       });
```

Comment: I don't think it does as "dynamicBtn" is reassigned at each iteration. Basically, with the current implementation, the last button should change text whatever button the user presses.